# How to I pass Date.now to .type() in my Cypress UI spec?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I'm trying to pass Date.now into a text field (so my tests can run over and over with new data). I've added the following, however I'm not having much luck.

The .type() only accepts strings.

```
var num = Date.now
        var n = num.toString()
cy.get('[formcontrolname="itemValue"]').type(n)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't checked the actual value of `num`, have you? Since it's a function, not a date in milliseconds. However, it should output *"function now() ..."* as a string. If not, then the problem is in cypress selector reference.

This should do the job, if all above conditions are met:

```
const num = Date.now();
const n = num.toString();
cy.get('[formcontrolname="itemValue"]').type(n);
```

Comment: Hello Samuli - Your answer worked! Thanks for replying :)

Comment: No problem, always happy to help :)